# unclear error, Invalid function SEARCH. - at )

Tags: couchbase, sql++

My couchbase version : Couchbase Server Enterprise Edition 6.0.3 build 2895. 
My Query :

```
SELECT t1.text
FROM bucket_name AS t1
WHERE SEARCH(t1, {
  "explain": false,
  "fields": [
     "*"
   ],
   "highlight": {},
   "query": {
     "match": "earth",
     "field": "text",
     "analyzer": "standard"
   },
   "size" : 10
})
```

i ran that query via couchbase web ui, then error shown'up, and just like :

```
"Invalid function SEARCH. - at )",
```

have no idea about `at )`

Answer (score 2):

The SEARCH() function in the N1QL is supported in 6.5.0 not in 6.0.3
. You can use 6.5.0 beta or in 6.0.3 use CURL() function described section 2.1 at the following link  https://blog.couchbase.com/n1ql-and-search-how-to-leverage-fts-index-in-n1ql-query/

https://blog.couchbase.com/tag/fts/